# Do something when window width less than 766px

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make responsive drop-down menu bar, and I want to set different jQuery event between PC and Mobile.

So I made some jQuery events that...

Do something if window width less than 767px or else....

This is my code here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {   
        $('.mGnb a').click(function() {
            $('#subLayer').slideToggle(200);
            return false;
        });  
    }
    else {  
        $('.mGnb a').hover(function() {
            $('#subLayer').slideUp(200);
            return false;
        });  
    }); 
});
```

It works fine. But the problem is when I resize the window, jQuery doesn't work. It works when I resize and Refresh(F5) the page.

What do I need to fix it ?

Comment: Despite that the correct answer is already provided, why do you want to do this with js? Maybe @media-querie would fit your purposes with CSS. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 5):

Use like this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
//your code here
}).resize();
```

Comment: And if you want to throttle the function calls: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/

Comment: Why do you call `.resize()` at the end ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov the function itself is inside resize handler and in first load it would not work if you don't use it last... It means resize is triggered when loaded...

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov : to make it work on the first load.

Comment: Sure, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.matchMedia`, for example:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 765px)").matches) {
  /* mobile view related javascript */
} else {
  /* desktop view related javascript */
}
```

More information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it on document ready. Attach an event handler to the resize event of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code with function and call it from window resize event like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     //your function here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do something on the window resize you might wanna add the event handler for `resize` event.

Something like this.

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        resize();
    })
});

function resize(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {   
        $('.mGnb a').click(function() {
            $('#subLayer').slideToggle(200);
            return false;
        });  
    }
    else {  
        $('.mGnb a').hover(function() {
            $('#subLayer').slideUp(200);
            return false;
        });  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(myfunc);
$(window).resize(myfunc);
function myfunc(){
if ($(window).width() < 767)
{   
    $('.mGnb a').click(function()
    {
        $('#subLayer').slideToggle(200);
        return false;
    });
}
else
{
    $("#header").mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({height: "96px"}, 200 ); 
    }); 
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your width only get's calculated on $(document).ready() , you should find a way of recalculating it every x seconds by something like a timer or so.

```
setInterval(function(){
var width = $(".element").width();
},100);
```

this way the variable width would update every 0.1 second.

Comment: You're  making it complicated for no reason, especially when you have the `resize` event at hand. You see, `JavaScript` is `event driven`. You need to give up your traditional programming model to make efficient use of all the features of `JavaScript` :)